# Use sed command for particular lines

Tags: sed, perl

I have a text file on a Linux machine and I want to run 3 sed commands for the lines entered by the user using a perl script. I am doing this manually till now.

The sed commands I have to use are :

```
sed -i "s/{+//" error.txt
sed -i "s/+}//" error.txt
sed -i "s/\[-.*-]//g" error.txt
```

`error.txt` is the file where I want to run these commands, but I want them to run on a particular line which I will enter.

Error.txt:

```
1:module counter ( clk, reset, enable, {+dat_out+} );

4:  input clk, [-reset ;-] {+reset, enable;+}

5:  wire   {+N69, N70, N71,+} N72, N73, N74, N75, N76, N77, N78, N79, N80, 

10:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[0]  ( [-.D(synopsis_unconnected),-] {+.D(N69),+} .E(N96), .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[0])

12:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[1]  ( {+.D(N70),+} .E(N94), .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[1])

14:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[2]  ( .D(N71), [-.E(synopsis_unconnected),-] {+.E(N92),+} .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[2])
```

expected output:

```
1:module counter ( clk, reset, enable, dat_out );

4:  input clk, [-reset ;-] {+reset, enable;+}

5:  wire   {+N69, N70, N71,+} N72, N73, N74, N75, N76, N77, N78, N79, N80, 

10:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[0]  (  .D(N69), .E(N96), .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[0])

12:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[1]  ( {+.D(N70),+} .E(N94), .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[1])

14:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[2]  ( .D(N71), [-.E(synopsis_unconnected),-] {+.E(N92),+} .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[2])
```

The codes are applied on Line 1 and Line 10.
Please suggest something

Comment: Add some sample text from the file including the line(s) that you want to edit and the expected output.

Comment: check now i have added the file

Comment: If you're using a perl script to obtain user input, it's hard to see a good reason to shell out to sed for the substitutions

Comment: I will take the input that on which line number does the user want to use the sed command.

Comment: This looks like `wdiff` output. What is the overall issue you are solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a condition in the form of e.g a search pattern:

```
sed -i -r '/^10?:/ {s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt
```

The substitutions are performed only if the line starts with `1:` or `10:`. This is the output:

```
1:module counter ( clk, reset, enable, dat_out );
4:  input clk, [-reset ;-] {+reset, enable;+}
5:  wire   {+N69, N70, N71,+} N72, N73, N74, N75, N76, N77, N78, N79, N80,
10:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[0]  (  .D(N69), .E(N96), .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[0])
12:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[1]  ( {+.D(N70),+} .E(N94), .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[1])
14:  EDFFX2AD \dat_out_sig_reg[2]  ( .D(N71), [-.E(synopsis_unconnected),-] {+.E(N92),+} .CK(clk), .Q(dat_out[2])
```

---

The condition can be on line numbers: this will only process the first line:

```
sed -i -r '1 {s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt
```

---

Since you mention Perl, you might prefer to use the following:

```
perl -i -pe 'if (/^10?:/) {s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt
```

or:

```
perl -i -pe 'if ($.==1 or $.==10) {s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt
```

Comment: For this code sed -i -r '1 {s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt ; Cant I use variable instead of 1? like $var=1 sed -i -r '$var {s/\{\+//; s/\+}//; s/\[-.*-]//g}' error.txt

Comment: @Coolstrike Yes, you can use a variable, but you should edit your post with the exact question and requirements. It seems that you are exposing only a part of a bigger problem: if you want better answers you should give a more comprehensive picture (as was suggested in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line or an range befor your `sed` command.

For your first example you can try for the 3rd line wich is numbered as #4:

```
sed "3 s/{+//" error.txt
```

Or if you need a script, you could work on this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Usage:\t ./my_sed.sh linenumber file\n"
sed "$1 s/{+//" $2
```

Comment: Can't I use a user input say a variable and then apply on the varaible value

Comment: Of course! You need to write a script to achive this. Review my edit, I give you a hint.